# Fire Ouibounce exit popup On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I'm using an exit popup script called "Ouibounce": https://github.com/carlsednaoui/ouibounce

I would like the popup to only fire when you click the tab or window exit buttons, instead of firing the moment you scroll over the toolbars.
Does anyone know if this is possible?
I googled and couldn't find anything about this, and tried to edit the javascript but my knowledge is just too limited.

Comment: After looking at it a bit, it seems that Ouibounce only triggers based on the mouse leaving the viewport. It doesn't seem to have any built in functionality for anything you're requesting. As far as the posibility - there are some things you can do for the exit with the "onbeforeunload" window event. However, it has limitations. Regarding going to a new tab - I am fairly certain there is no way to detect that. But - OUIbounce has a sensitivity setting that may simulate what you need (basically, make it so it has to leave far enough to reach the tabs). A thought, anyways.